# Composition with indicator function?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a function and let $\boldsymbol{1}$ be the indicator function of some set $E.$ I have seen this a lot:
$$\boldsymbol{1}_{f^{-1}(E)} = \boldsymbol{1}_{E} \circ f.$$

Is this just a notation thing, or is this $\textit{actually}$ a composition? If it is a composition, I am not seeing it.

Comment: Plug in an argument to the functions on both sides and check when you get one and zero respectively. If math were just a notational thing we could pack up and go home.

Comment: It is composition, when is the left hand side equal to one and when 0? And when is the right hand side equal to 1 and when 0?